# What to do when jQuery isn't working?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, debugging, wordpress-theming

I am running a WordPress website. jQuery 1.8.3 is loaded from the `wp-includes` directory.

I wrote the most basic of jQuery code... 
http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("jQuery works!!");
});
</script>
```

Nothing happens when the page loads. So I check the browser console...

Depending on the page, I've seen:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

or

`Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function`

Which is pointing to:

`$(document).ready(function(){`

How is it, that the simplest of jQuery functionality doesn't work ... at all? Am I doing something wrong?

I am used to programming with PHP and getting an error outputted right on the page the second something doesn't work and it's usually very easy to locate and correct the error.

What are common debugging techniques for jQuery when a situation like this is encountered?

How can I make this basic jQuery function work with my WordPress website?

There are no WordPress plugins enabled, other than my own. I also have a fresh blank theme. So there isn't a theme or plugin conflict.

Comment: "jQuery 1.8.3 is loaded" --- why do you think so? "What are common debugging techniques" --- the first step is to open a debugger, then open the page and see what happens (assuming the break on uncaught exceptions is turned on)

Comment: Because I enqueued the script in my code, and it's outputted when I view source.

Comment: it doesn't mean it loaded. It means that some `<script>` tag is somewhere in the document. Open chrome dev tools and look at Network tab

Comment: @MichaelEcklund: Your error messages don't agree. Are you loading jQuery before or after your script?

Comment: "As a professional Minnesota Website Developer for the past four years", "I am an experienced Minnesota Web Designer" --- hehe, that made my morning

Comment: @Blender Loading in the header... BEFORE my script.

Comment: @Michael Ecklund: have you checked network tab and tried to use debugger? Why do you continue guessing instead of getting know for sure why it happens?

Comment: @MichaelEcklund: Post your template (or at least the parts where you load the scripts). Is jQuery actually loading (no 404 errors)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WordPress calls [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) automatically, resulting in the `$` variable not being available.

Try this instead:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    alert("jQuery works!!");
});
```

That uses `jQuery` instead of `$` in the global namespace, but uses the function parameter to redefine `$`, allowing you to use it as expected within the scope of the document-ready function.

It's not directly relevant to your problem, but this code can also be shortened even more, like this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    alert("jQuery works!!");
});
```

Comment: If it conflicted it wouldn't be "$ **is not defined**" error, but a error about not existing methods called

Comment: Possibly the WP version of jquery calls [jQuery.noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) automatically?

Comment: @Michael Ecklund: it's identical to yours (unless you're doing some weird things you didn't tell to us)

Comment: @jcsanyi I really appreciate your friendly and helpful response, unlike some of these other self absorbed jerks on this website. WordPress does call `jQuery.noConflict()`. I am new to jQuery and didn't realize you could do that. Thanks again for your constructive response.

Comment: It's good practice to *always* write `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {` instead of `$(document).ready(function() {` so code works regardless of whether or not there's a `jQuery.noConflict();` call

Comment: Answer updated to better reflect what the actual problem was.

Answer (score 2):

WordPress always runs jQuery in no conflict mode. So rather than using `$` you should use `jQuery`.